# Remove duplicates in listagg?

Tags: informatica, listagg

input data

```
ID   CID
1    101,103
1    101
```

In The Target, I am getting like this, I used listagg function

```
ID   CID
1    101,103,101
```

But I Want the output like below

```
ID    CID
1    101,103
```

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct first then use listag. You can refer to below SQL.

```
SELECT
 subqry.ID as id,
 listagg(cid,',') within group(order by(id)) as cid
FROM 
(select distinct ID, CID from FROM Table1) subqry -- this will deduplicate CIDs first
group by id 
Order by 1
--
```

Comment: I am using distinct in subquery but still same output

Comment: can you pls post your query in the question/